# How is Async.map implemented? Use of Array.map with asynchronous callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

What is the best way to take control over a Array.map when it's using asynchronous function inside the callback function?

I don't want to use [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async) library, just vanilla JS. So I would like to know how to implement my how Async.map method.

Let's use this example:

```
function async(arg, callback) {
  var delay=Math.random()*3*1000; // 0- 3000 delay
  console.log('do something with \''+arg+'\', return '+delay/1000+' sec later');
  setTimeout(function() { callback(arg * 2); }, delay);
}


var items = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ];
var results = [];

results=items.map(function(item) {
  async(item, function(item){
    console.log("Done something, result: "+item);
  })
});

console.log("**This should be my last operation**");
```

The output of my script is something like this:

```
do something with '1', return 0.9073115468490869 sec later
...
do something with '6', return 2.3373042417224497 sec later
**This should be my last operation***
Done something, result: 10
...
Done something, result: 8
```

But I want this:

```
do something with '1', return 0.9073115468490869 sec later
...
do something with '6', return 2.3373042417224497 sec later
Done something, result: 10
...
Done something, result: 8
**This should be my last operation**
```

Comment: Why not use the async library?  The alternative is to implement `async.map` yourself, which is more error-prone.

Comment: I thought that it would be a good exercise to understand how it should be done taking inspiration from this forEach control flow pattern: http://book.mixu.net/node/ch7.html#-chapter_number-2-2-control-flow-pattern-2-full-parallel-an-asynchronous-parallel-for-loop

Comment: That's fair, but you should amend your question.  The answer to "what is the best way" is to use a library.  The answer to "how is `async.map` implemented" seems to be what you're really looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use map with asynchronous operations. Array.map is a synchronous operation, so it will execute the functions that are inside and will NOT wait for the asynchronous operations. This is why you see your log like that.

You can use Async, if you will need it for more things.
Or you can use a library like async-each (which is just 35 lines of code) https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-each